# Run my third-party DLL file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I am not sure if this is possible or not with PowerShell.

But basically I have a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) program that configures a program called EO Server. The EO Server has an API, and I make a reference to EOServerAPI.dll to make the following code run.

```
using EOserverAPI;
...
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String MDSConnString="Data Source=MSI;Initial Catalog=EOMDS;Integrated Security=True;";

    //Create the connection
    IEOMDSAPI myEOMDSAPI = EOMDSAPI.Create(MDSConnString);

    //Get JobID
    Guid myMasterJobID = myEOMDSAPI.GetJobID("myJobRocks");
}
```

Is it possible to interact with an API DLL file and make the same types of calls as you would in a Windows Forms application?

Answer (score 45):

Yes, you can:

```
Add-Type -Path $customDll
$a = new-object custom.type
```

You call a static method like so:

```
[custom.type]::method()
```

Instead of Add-Type, you can also use reflection:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($customDll)
```

(Note that even the above is calling the Reflection library and the LoadFile static method.)

Comment: I am lost with the second statement.
$a= new-object custom.type

I don't know how to call my custom.type
Could you help me?

Comment: @MicroSumol The type is fully qualified name (namespace+classname)of your class. Eg. A.B.C.ClassName

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at the blog post *[Load a Custom DLL from PowerShell](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/10/27/load-a-custom-dll-from-powershell)*. If you can interact with an object in .NET, you can probably do it in PowerShell too.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the other offered solutions don't work for me, here it's an alternative that works perfectly for me:

```
$AssemblyPath = "C:\SomePath\SomeLIB.dll"
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($AssemblyPath)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)
```

Comment: Do you know why Add-Type doesn't work with your dll? What kind of error message do you get? Or is there something unusual about the dll?

Comment: Hi @Blaisem, my post is from 3 years and an half ago. I don't remember anymore, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

c# dll

```
Add-Type -Path $dllPath
(new-object namespace.class)::Main() #Where namespace=dllnamespace, class=dllclass, Main()=dllstartvoid
```

info. get namespace&classes

```
$types = Add-Type -Path $dllPath -PassThru
$types | ft fullname
$types
```

if it's not "executable" dll (something get/set dll) then this is the best that i know (not needed vs for sample dll creating):

[https://kazunposh.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/проверка-корректного-ввода-distinguished-name-в-скри/](https://kazunposh.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-distinguished-name-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8/)