# Import-Module -Assembly error

Tags: powershell, import-module

I am trying to write PowerShell and am failing miserably.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Import-Module -Assembly PowerShellXrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.dll
```

and

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted 
Import-Module -Assembly "PowerShellXrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.dll"
```

and get the following error.

```
Import-Module : Cannot bind parameter 'Assembly'. Cannot convert the
"PowerShellXrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.dll" value of type "System.String"
to type "System.Reflection.Assembly".
At line:1 char:25
+ Import-Module -Assembly PowerShellXrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.dll
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Module], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

The PowerShell script is saved in the same location as the `PowerShellXrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.dll` assembly. I have also tried  including the full path to the assembly with no luck.

Comment: `-Assembly` parameter want `Assembly` object not path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run my third-party DLL file with PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972141/run-my-third-party-dll-file-with-powershell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import a PowerShell module from a DLL file simply pass the filename:

```
Import-Module 'PowerShellXrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.dll'
```

Use the full path if the file is not located in one of the folders listed in `$env:PSModulePath`:

```
Import-Module 'C:\path\to\PowerShellXrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.dll'
```

As [documented](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849725.aspx) the `-Assembly` parameter is for importing assembly *objects*, not assembly *files*.

> **-Assembly<Assembly[]>**
>
> Imports the cmdlets and providers implemented in the specified assembly objects. Enter a variable that contains assembly objects or a command that creates assembly objects. You can also pipe an assembly object to Import-Module.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `-Assembly` parameter you can use the following:

```
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('PowerShellXrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.dll')
Import-Module -Assembly $assembly
```