# Powershell - Taskbar icons, Never Combine, Hide Lables, Group By App ID

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

In Windows 10:

Is there a way to use Powershell to modify the taskbar functionality?  I know 7++Taskbar Tweaker does this, but I was curious if this can be done via Powershell as I can't use Taskbar Tweaker.

**Goal:**

Have multiple icons of same program open, next to each other, with no labels.

For example if I have a copy of PROD open in SSMS, and DEV in another instance of SSMS, I would like to click once just on the PROD (or DEV) without waiting for the hover to come down.  I know this is not a major deal, just curious if powershell can do it and how.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It may be  a little late but why do you want to use powershell specificly? Aren't you comfortable with the native Windows Settings?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned 7+ Taskbar Tweaker. There's a library of the same author, [7+ Taskbar Tweaking Library](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaking-library), which you can use. Regarding PowerShell, this might help: [Run my third-party DLL file with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972141/run-my-third-party-dll-file-with-powershell).